# Minimum value of every group in table

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a table with this format. How can I get the minimum value of every group and put it in another list?

```
{{x1, x2, x3, x4}, {x5, x6, x7, x8}, {x9, x10, x11, x12}}
```

Comment: `Min /@ yourList`? Look up [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) in the documentation (its infix form is `/@`).

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

```
m = 
 {{4, 2, 3, 1}, 
  {5, 8, 5, 7}, 
  {4, 3, 3, 3}};
```

Using `ArrayReduce` (new in 12.2)

Row Minima

```
ArrayReduce[Min, m, 2]
```

{1, 5, 3}

Column Minima

```
ArrayReduce[Min, m, 1]
```

{4, 2, 3, 1}

Answer (score 1):

```
m = {{4, 2, 3, 1}, {5, 8, 5, 7}, {4, 3, 3, 3}};
```

---

Using `Outer`, `Thread` and `Min`:

```
{#, Min @@@ Outer[List, #] & /@ {#, Thread@#} &@#} &@m

(*{{{4, 2, 3, 1}, {5, 8, 5, 7}, {4, 3, 3, 3}}, {{1, 5, 3}, {4, 2, 3, 1}}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Random enough but the results can be verified easily by inspection with the following strategy.

```
SeedRandom[11];
(m = Range[21] // Partition[#, 7] & // 
    RotateLeft[#, {4, 1}] &) // MatrixForm

RankedMin[#, 1] & /@ m

MinimalBy[#, # &] & /@ m // Flatten

Min /@ m (* comment from @MarcoB *)
```

---

*Result:*:

```
{8, 15, 1}
```

---

For columns, use `Transpose@m` with all variants, e.g. :

```
Min /@ Transpose@m
```

> {4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3}